Tkinter - Side by Side and Bottom Frames
I'm trying to setup a simple Box entry form in Tkinter. I'm trying to have two entry boxes side-by-side with the labels above them, and another one placed below it.
This is the closest I've gotten, though the first label and entry are misaligned:

Code:
def login_selection(self):
    loginf = tk.Frame(master=self,relief=RAISED,borderwidth=1)
    loginf.grid(row=2,column=0)
    userf = tk.Frame(master=loginf, borderwidth=1)
    serverf = tk.Frame(master=loginf,borderwidth=1)
    userf.pack()
    userl = tk.Label(master=userf, text="Username")
    usere = tk.Entry(master=userf)
    passl = tk.Label(master=userf, text="Password")
    passe = tk.Entry(master=userf)
    userl.pack(side=TOP)
    usere.pack(side=LEFT)
    passl.pack(side=TOP)
    passe.pack(side=LEFT)

    serverf.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    serverl = tk.Label(master=serverf, text="Server")
    servere = tk.Entry(master=serverf)
    serverl.pack()
    servere.pack()

Thanks for any help!

You can use the object.grid() method to organize your GUI.
def login_selection(self):
    loginf = tk.Frame(master=self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
    loginf.grid(row=2, column=0)

    # User Frame
    userf = tk.Frame(master=loginf, borderwidth=1)
    userf.pack()
    userl = tk.Label(master=userf, text="Username")
    usere = tk.Entry(master=userf)
    passl = tk.Label(master=userf, text="Password")
    passe = tk.Entry(master=userf, show="*")

    userl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5, sticky="e")
    usere.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    passl.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2.5, pady=2.5, sticky="e")
    passe.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)

    # Server Frame
    serverf = tk.Frame(master=loginf, borderwidth=1)
    serverf.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    serverl = tk.Label(master=serverf, text="Server")
    servere = tk.Entry(master=serverf)

    serverl.pack()
    servere.pack()

The object.grid() uses rows and columns instead of set positions like TOP or BOTTOM. This creates an opportunity for more variation in the position of GUI elements. Here is a picture of the GUI:
a picture of the updated GUI

Thanks! That works great! Didn't realize you could create grids in grids!

You're welcome! Make sure to mark the answer as the confirmed answer.

**def login_selection(self):
loginf = tk.Frame(master=self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
loginf.grid(row=2, column=0)
# User Frame
userf = tk.Frame(master=loginf, borderwidth=1)
userf.pack()
userl = tk.Label(master=userf, text="Username")
usere = tk.Entry(master=userf)
passl = tk.Label(master=userf, text="Password")
passe = tk.Entry(master=userf, show="*")

userl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5, sticky="e")
usere.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
passl.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2.5, pady=2.5, sticky="e")
passe.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)

# Server Frame
serverf = tk.Frame(master=loginf, borderwidth=1)
serverf.pack(side=BOTTOM)
serverl = tk.Label(master=serverf, text="Server")
servere = tk.Entry(master=serverf)

serverl.pack()
servere.pack()**


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I kindly request that you format the code
